# when i do knife cookbook upload 'cookbookname'

Tags: installation, chef-infra, knife

knife cookbook upload 'cookbookname'

i am getting the following error.

```
ubuntu@mychefclient:~/chef-repo$ knife cookbook upload redis
Uploading redis        [0.1.0]
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:76:in `put'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:151:in `block in uploader_function_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `call'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `loop'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
```

Comment: The real error is `"Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)"`. Seems like your connection was down, or your DNS server is shaky, or the domain they're looking up is invalid.

Comment: How to solve the issue @jonathon-reinhart

Comment: Looks like a transient networking issue. Unfair to ask us to solve this for you. Does knife work for other commands? For example try "knife client list". If that's also broken then your issue is which your knife configuration file.

Comment: You can try to access your chef server via browser to see if the name of your chef server can be resolved.

Comment: Has this upload ever worked?  Is this an OSS Chef Server or Hosted? If it's OSS: where is it hosted and what does its hostname resolve to (run `hostname`, `hostname -f` on the server)?

Comment: yes knife client list is working properly

Comment: No im trying for the first time. it is hosted its hostname is mychefserver.example.com @cbi

Comment: Try setting the IP of your chef server in your `knife.rb` config, for example, `chef_server_url          'http://10.33.33.33'` for a chef server 11.0.8 server set to run on HTTP instead of HTTPS (local vagrant testing).

Comment: i reconfigured the server "chef-server-ctl reconfigure" then i created new cookbook and uploaded now its working.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct, even if it is your own! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because knife cannot access the Chef Server. Please ensure you can access the server (try pinging and telneting). It is most likely a local network issue.